# Minishift/CDK getsockopt: connection refused ()

Tags: openshift, minishift, redhat-containers

Good day

Referring to https://developers.redhat.com/products/cdk/hello-world/#fndtn-windows

Having: CDK v3.6.0-1, minishift v1.24.0, Virtualbox v5.2.6, Windows 10

When running cmd `minishift start` from Windows PowerShell, Minishift VM is running, but getting the below errors. I've disabled Windows F/W settings as well

> Starting OpenShift cluster .......................................................Error during
>   'cluster up' execution: Error starting the cluster. ssh command error:
>   command : /var/lib/minishift/bin/oc cluster up --base-dir
>   /var/lib/minishift/base --image
>   'registry.access.redhat.com/openshift3/ose-${component}:v3.10.45'
>   --public-hostname 192.168.99.100 --routing-suffix 192.168.99.100.nip.io err
>   : exit status 1 output
>
> E1126 06:58:05.268672    2423 run_self_hosted.go:542] API server
>   error: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/healthz?timeout=32s: dial tcp
>   192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused () Error: timed out waiting for the condition

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

This is [known issue](https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/21420) with Minishift, respectively oc-cluster-up which Minishift uses under the hood. Unfortunately I am not aware of any fix or nice workaround for it. From my experience there are however several aspects which contributes to this failure: slow machine and slow network. You can try to be connected via cable not WiFi and assign more CPUs to Minishift VM. Other tip which might help is to enable image caching in Minishift which might speed the start a little bit.